# Postman - Failing to get value from an object that has `:` in the property key

Tags: postman

I'm struggling to get value from an object that has `:` within the key name of property.

This is how my Response Body looks:

```
{
    "links": {
        "content": {
            "href": "http://*********",
            "templated": false,
            "type": "application/hal+json"
        },
        "test:search": [
            {
                "title": "Some title",
                "href": "http://*************",
                "type": "application/hal+json"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I try to get the `href` value from `test:search`, Postman is giving me an error:

> "Missing ";" before statement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you add it to the `Tests` tab:

```
_.each(pm.response.json().links['test:search'], (item) => {
    console.log(item.href)
    pm.environment.set('href', item.href)
})
```

[image: Test Request]

If you were to use this to reference the property `pm.response.json().links.test:search` it would fail to set the variable.

[image: Failed Request]

Comment: It works!! Thank you! 
I have been trying too solve this for some hours. You made my day :D